# Are Planet Asset Activations Bundled or Synchronous?

Tags: planet

I was wondering if planet asset activations are linked/bundled or synchronous for item types so for example
If I use --activate PSOrthoTile analytic, does it automatically activate analytic_xml and also analytic_dn? or would I have to run --activate PSOrthoTile analytic_xml and --activate PSOrthoTile analytic_dn separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are related assets that get activated simultaneously with a single request. Typically this is the GeoTIFF and the XML but there are a few others.

Notably, the DN and analytic are *not* related, and it would take two requests to activate these.

You can always check the API responses and see which assets change status to `activating` after a single activation request.